# Why does adding a sum to a long value lead to a subtraction?

Tags: java, math, timestamp, integer, long-integer

I encountered a troublesome issue and I can't really explain to myself why it is appearing.

Basically I want to add time to a timestamp (a simple long).

I understand it the following. If I add time to a timestamp I end in the future. If I subtract time to the timestamp I end in the past.

In my example it is the other way around. If I add something to my timestamp it is reduced and if I subtract something is added.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      static final int MONTH_IN_SECONDS = 2629743;

      final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("Current: " + current);

      final long future = System.currentTimeMillis() + (MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3);
      System.out.println("Addition: " + future);

      final long past = System.currentTimeMillis() - (MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3);
      System.out.println("Subtraction: " + past);
    }
}
```

Result (compare the first 5 chars):

```
Current:     1582275101365
Addition:    1581574395774 // smaller than current even though it should be greater
Subtraction: 1582975806958 // great than current even though it should be smaller
```

Why does this happend? Does the term `(MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3)` overflow because it is only an Integer and thus the calculation does not work (or ends in a negative value)?

If I change the term to `(MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000L * 3)` it seems to work correctly. Is it because the complete term is casted to a `long`?

Comment: It’s still not clear how “Subtraction” becomes “Minus” during printing, but anyway. You already answered your question yourself. You could have simplified it by just `System.out.println(MONTH_IN_SECONDS*1000*3);`…

Comment: You seemed to have answered your question. All your guesses are correct. It is due to an overflow, and the complete term does become a `long` if you do `1000L`.

Comment: I used Netbeans as IDE which didn't mark this as possible issue. IntelliJ shows a message that it could cause problems so the issue could have been prevented if I used a different IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
(MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3)
```

That's integer multiplication that's overflowing, and resulting in a negative number:

```
System.out.println((MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3));
```

That outputs `-700705592`. You'd have to declare `MONTH_IN_SECONDS` as `long`, or otherwise change the expression so that the result is `long`-typed.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the term (MONTH_IN_SECONDS * 1000 * 3) overflow because it is
>   only an Integer and thus the calculation does not work (or ends in a
>   negative value)?

Month in seconds? Google says 2,630,000. (Though I see you have 2629743.)

```
    2,630,000 * 1000 * 3 = 7,890,000,000

Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31 = 2,147,483,648
```

So yeah, it's an *integer overflow*.